# LINQ Where expression to extend

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am wondering how to 'finish' a LINQ to Entities where expression. This is what I wanted to write:

```
IQueryable<Products> qry = ...
qry = ApplyFilter(qry, p => p.Name, "hello");

private IQueryable<Products> ApplyFilter(
          IQueryable<Products> qry, 
          Expression<Func<Products,String>> field, 
          String likeFilter)
{
  // ???
  return qry.Where( field.Contains( likeFilter )); 
}
```

The call syntax is important (needs to be simple and clean), the function arguments and the function body is the weak point. :( I am getting better in lambda functions and expressions, but not enough good at this time :( Thanks for all the help and advices!

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do with the ApplyFilter method. Can you give more detail?

Comment: this is what I usually write: `Products.Where( p => p.Name.Contains("hello"))`, now I want to write `ApplyFilter(Products, p=>p.Name, "Hello")`. The total environment is complicated, this is the root problem to solve, other small problems can be resolved easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will look better if you design your method as an generic extension method (like the other linq extensions).

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Func<T, string> field, string likeFilter)
    {
        return qry.Where(x => field(x).Contains(likeFilter));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IQueryable<Product> qry = new List<Product>() 
    { 
        new Product() {Name = "Ball", Category = "Sport"},
        new Product() {Name = "Bag", Category = "Other"},
        new Product() {Name = "Sport bag", Category = "Sport"},
    }.AsQueryable();

var result = qry.ApplyFilter(p => p.Category, "Sport");
```

Additional you can add caseSensitive flag variable to your extension mehtod.

**EDIT** - 
Try this modification:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Func<T, string> field, string likeFilter)
{
    foreach (var item in qry)
    {
        if (field(item).Contains(likeFilter))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunetly atm I can't realize if this broke the IQueryable clauses accumulation.

**EDIT 2**

Ok finnaly I decided to implement as building expression tree so I can be sure it'll be translated to SQL successful. The final (I hope :D) solution:

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> qry, Expression<Func<T, string>> field, string likeFilter)
{
    var member = field.Body as MemberExpression;
    var propInfo = member.Member as PropertyInfo;

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, propInfo);

    var containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains");
    var body = Expression.Call(prop, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(likeFilter));
    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);

    return qry.Where(expr);
}
```

Comment: You're right, the final code will be generic, I tried to simplify the question as much as it can be. Unfortunately, in LINQ to Entities this code also drops exception: _An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities._ :(

Comment: Updated the answer. I tested it with EF.

Comment: Very similar to @MartinLiversage's solution. Seems also working! :) Thanks for your time and patience!

Comment: Actually his solution is similar to mine cause he edited his answer after me :P

Comment: Ohh sorry :( For some reason I read that first, before yours :)

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak: My solution is slightly shorter because you do not need to create a new parameter for the lambda. Other than that, I believe we came up with the same solution independently but Victor's suggestion about using an extension method is good advice.

Answer (score 3):

As I have now figured that you do not want to compile the expression you need to build a new more complex expression based on the provided expression to retrieve the field value. I have taken the liberty to make the solution generic because the `Products` type is not needed by the code:

```
private IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(
          IQueryable<T> qry,
          Expression<Func<T,String>> field,
          String likeFilter)
{
  var methodInfo = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains");
  var methodCallExpression = Expression
    .Call(field.Body, methodInfo, Expression.Constant(likeFilter));
  var predicate = Expression
    .Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(methodCallExpression, field.Parameters[0]);
  return qry.Where(predicate);
}
```

If the `field` expression is `p => p.Name` the expression in `predicate` is `p => p.Name.Contains(likeFilter)`. Entity Framework is able to understand this expression and convert it into SQL.

Comment: However I like this solution, but unfortunately the EF drops an exception _An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities._ I try to use it LINQ to Entities environment... :(

Comment: Isn't `Compile` the opposite of what you want here? LINQ to Enitities needs to look at what's inside the `Expression` and translate it into SQL. Compiling it breaks that.

Comment: I agree. `Compile` will attempt to call a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The Linq query will ultimately be translated to SQL. If you have arbitrary functions in the where clause you will get the "invoke not supported" error. Does the following work for you?

```
public class Products
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


static void Main()
{
    IQueryable<Products> qry = new List<Products> {         
        new Products() {Name = "Football" },
        new Products() {Name = "Baseball" },
        new Products() {Name = "Glove" },
    }.AsQueryable();

    var r = ApplyFilter(qry, p => p.Name.Contains("ball"));
}


private static IQueryable<Products> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<Products> qry, Expression<Func<Products, bool>> predicate)
{
    return qry.Where(predicate);
}
```