# How can I make Linq extension method available for the entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, extension-methods

I wrote a method that extends `System.Linq` class. My `ContainsAnyWord` method allows me to search all words in a string against a string instead of comparing one string to another.

Here is the method that I wrote to extend `Linq`

```
public static class LinqExtension
{

    public static bool ContainsAnyWord(this string value, string searchFor)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchFor))
        {
            value = value.ToLower();

            IEnumerable<string> tags = StopwordTool.GetPossibleTags(searchFor);

            return tags.Contains(value);

        }

        return false;

    }

}
```

This extension method works great on an `IEnumerable` object. But when I want to use it on `IQueryable` object I get the following error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean
>   ContainsAnyWord(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method
>   cannot be translated into a store expression.

The following example works great because I am working with a list.

```
using(var conn = new AppContext())
{

    var allUsers = conn.Users.GetAll().ToList();
    var foundUsers = allUsers.Where
    (
        user => 
               user.FirstName.ContainsAnyWord("Some Full Name Goes Here")
            || user.LastName.ContainsAnyWord("Some Full Name Goes Here")
    ).ToList();

}
```

But the following example does not work because I am working with `IQueryable` which gives me the error listed above.

```
using(var conn = new AppContext())
{

    var allUsers = conn.Users.Where
    (
        user => 
            user.FirstName.ContainsAnyWord("Some Full Name Goes Here") 
         || user.LastName.ContainsAnyWord("Some Full Name Goes Here")
    ).ToList();

}
```

How can I fix this issue and make this method available for `IQueryable` object?

**UPDATED**

Based on the feedback I got below, I tried to implement this using `IQueryable` like so

```
    public static IQueryable<T> ContainsAnyWord<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string searchFor)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchFor))
        {
            IEnumerable<string> tags = StopwordTool.GetPossibleTags(searchFor);

            return query.Where(item => tags.Contains(item));

        }

        return query;

    }
```

But this is also giving me an error

[image]

Comment: You extended `string`, not `IQueryable<string>`.

Comment: [this might be interessting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24524745/2441442)

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt implementing IQueryable will not work inside the Where(). I need my code to work in the where because I want to be able to apply some `OR` operator logic

Comment: Whats wrong with @GeorgeVovos answers? `T : User`, `query.Where(user => tags.Contains(user.Prop1) || tags.Contains(user.Prop2)`

Comment: I need it to be generic so I can use it with any entity not just user

Comment: Then just look at my commented link. Generic makes no sense in this case... I don't think an invoice, a shopping cart, a blog entry has a username or password or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that this has to be translated to SQL at the end. 
Obviously ContainsAnyWord cannot be translated to SQL...
So ,save your names in a List/Array and try

```
 user =>  yourlist.Contains(  user.FirstName)
```

EF will translate this to a WHERE ..IN

There is no need for a method but if for some reason you want it

```
internal static class MyClass2
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ContainsAnyWord<T>(this IQueryable<T> value, string searchFor) where T: User
    {
        var names = searchFor.Split(' ').ToList();
        return value.Where(u => names.Contains(u.DisplayName));
    }
}
```

You can use it like

```
var result=conn.Users.ContainsAnyWord("abc def ght");
```

Comment: Great point. How would the first parameter of my method look like in this case? Or how would I let my extension method accepts something like user.FirstName (or what ever property I am using)

Comment: @MikeA Check my updated answer.As I said though,you don't need a method...

Comment: @MikeA but if you need something more general check Scott Chamberlain's answer

Comment: No need to do the `.Split(' ')`, You could make `searchFor` a `IEnumerable<string>` or pass in a string and call `GetPossibleTags(searchFor)` instead.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain your are correct but if we wants to use it  in many times better to do it here than every time he calls the method

Comment: GetPossibleTags(searchFor) return `IEnumerable<string>` with all the possible words, excluding the common words like and, are, is....

Comment: @MikeA I don't get this.What's the problem? Call GetPossibleTags to get the names...

Answer (score 1):

Linq to Entities converts Methods into database expressions. You can not implement an extension to System.String and expect it to be translated into a T-SQL expression, wich is what internally Entity Framework does.

My suggestion is trying to work around using pre-defined Linq methods. Try using Contains method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods inside the query expression the expression parser provided by the Linq to Entites does not know how to handle. The only thing you can really do is write a extension method that takes in a `IQueryable<T>` and build up the expression internally inside the function instead of calling `Where(`

This below code is totally untested and is something I came up with off the top of my head. But you would need to do something like this

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereContainsAnyWord<T>(this IQueryable<T> @this, Expression<Func<T, string>> selector, string searchFor)
{
    var tags = StopwordTool.GetPossibleTags(searchFor); //You might need a .ToArray() here.

    var selectedItems = @this.GroupBy(selector);
    var filteredItems = selectedItems.Where(selectedItem => tags.Contains(selectedItem.Key.ToLower()));
    var result = filteredItems.SelectMany(x => x);
    return result;
}
```

used like

```
using(var conn = new AppContext())
{

    var allUsers = conn.Users.WhereContainsAnyWord(user => user.FirstName, "Some Full Name Goes Here").ToList();

}
```

Here is a simpiler non generic version

```
public static IQueryable<User> WhereContainsAnyWord(this IQueryable<User> @this, string searchFor)
{
    var tags = StopwordTool.GetPossibleTags(searchFor); //You might need a .ToArray() here.

    return @this.Where(user => tags.Contains(user.DisplayName.ToLower()));
}
```

used like

```
using(var conn = new AppContext())
{

    var allUsers = conn.Users.WhereContainsAnyWord("Some Full Name Goes Here").ToList();

}
```

Comment: what does the `@` simple does here? also, why do you do the `GroupBy`

Comment: The @ lets you use the word `this` as a variable name because `this` is a reserved word. calling the first parameter `@this` in a extension method is a habit I picked up a while ago from somewhere. The `GroupBy`/`.SelectMany` pair is a hack so I can filter based on the passed in `selector` but make the result the function returns still be `T` instead of the output of `selector`. If I had more time I would just write [a custom `Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) to return a annonamous type, but the GroupBy was quicker.

Comment: This work good. But how would I use it to check multiple properties? for example `FirstName = "Something" || LastName = "Something"` notice with the method I had I am able to do this.