# Is it possible to Extend String class while supporting Linq to SQL translation?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an extension method like this :

```
public static bool SpecialContain(this string source, string searchTerm)
{
    return source.Contains(searchTerm + "blob");
}
```

Now, I want to make it translatable to LINQ to SQL (EntityFramework). Is it possible? In other words, I want to be able to write a query like this (with the above implementations I will get a Linq to Sql translation exception):

```
var q = from r in context.Students.Where(o=> o.Name.SpecialContain("Jhon"));
```

Comment: Extend the IQuerable, look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538286

Comment: @MarcusHöglund It is not my case. I exactly want to have such ability (Adding extension to String type, not adding extension to IQueryable)

Comment: In this case, https://weblogs.asp.net/Dixin/EntityFramework.Functions#Model_defined_function can help you.